# Drawing mud map

Tags: python, graph, visualization, graphviz, mud

I'm trying to draw map of some mud. I have used python and graphviz to get something like:

http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/5222/arrasz.png

As you can see we have some locations and going N/S/W/E/Up/Down we are going to other location.

Is it possible, with graphviz, to draw this map to have north locations up to south, and east locations on the right of west locations?

I mean like that:

```
some        --- E --->   some
location   <--- W ---    location 2
                            .
                           / \   |
                            |    |

                            N    S

                            |    |
                                \ /   
                                 `
                          some location 3
```

Or maybe there is some better tool to draw it automatically than graphviz?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to produce a correct *and* readable map in all cases, because the N/S and E/W axis are not really enforced in muds. For example you *could* have an E/W connection from your "some location" to "some location 3", which would mean (to a naive implementation" that they are at the same height (on the N/S axis), whereas the fact that there's another path between them that takes exactly 1 step on the N/S axis would imply that they are on *different* heights.

Answer (score 5):

People have asked about [improving Graphviz layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278030/improving-graphviz-layout) before, but I think that Graphviz is overkill here.

If you have a standard MUD layout like this:

[image: simple MUD layout]

...then you've got some fairly **strong constraints** about where rooms are.  Graphviz doesn't know about those constraints, so it won't do as good a job as a simple algorithm like:

1. Pick a starting location on the grid
2. Traverse through each room using e.g. a [depth-first traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)
3. Move one unit to the N, S, E, or W for each new room

If you don't want to write visualization code, you could (perhaps) just do the above approach as a pre-processing step for Graphviz, using it as a way of assigning ranks to each room.  Then (hopefully) Graphviz would produce the correct output.

**Edit:** for example, some pseudocode:

```
visit(initialRoom, 0, 0)

def visit(curRoom, curX, curY)
  if curRoom == null return

  print "in room " + curRoom + " at location " + curX + ", " + curY

  visit(curRoom.northNeighbor, curX,   curY-1)
  visit(curRoom.southNeighbor, curX,   curY+1)
  visit(curRoom.westNeighbor,  curX-1, curY)
  visit(curRoom.eastNeighbor,  curX+1, curY)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [node rank](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d%3arank) to force the vertical level of each node. This would insure that things are in the correct order north by south. You would have to preprocess the MUD map to figure out the ranking. You label a group of nodes to be of the "same" rank. You would process the MUD map and determine what group of room nodes all lie at the same level in the North/South direction. Example:

```
R1    R2
|     |
R3 -- R4--R5
```

For this map, you could have something like this:

```
digraph M {
    R1->R3;
    R2->R4;
    R3->R1;
    R3->R4;
    R4->R2;
    R4->R5;
    {rank=same;R1;R2}
    {rank=same;R3;R4;R5}
 }
```

I am not able to find a way to force the horizontal ordering. This would mean East/West would still possibly not line up correctly. It may work 90% of the time once you have the rank setup because the other rooms will help give it context.

Comment: Thank you. It will help. But if somebody know way which don't need to analyzing all map to know which ranks are same I'm still interested.

Answer (score 1):

I think the subgraphs (see [dotguide](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf) page 23) and the rank property (see [dotguide](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf) page 17) might be methods to better organize the graph

The following might be an alternative to Graphviz:

- http://gephi.org/ provides some [python bindings](http://gephi.org/2009/libgexf-011-is-out/) the newer versions even supports python as a scripting language inside the app.
- http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/index.html produces nice 3D graphs and can be controlled via python

Answer (score 0):

To build a map as a grid in graphviz, you can use the `neato` engine and absolute positioning nodes by coordinates `nodename [pos="coordinateX,coordinateY"]`. Graphviz code:

```
digraph Mud_Map {
    layout=neato
    splines=ortho
    node [label="" width=.5 height=.5 pin=true shape=box]
    "n0,0" [pos="0,0"]
    "n1,0" [pos="1,0"]
    "n1,-1" [pos="1,-1"]
   
    "n0,0" -> "n1,0" [xlabel="E"]
    "n1,0" -> "n0,0" [xlabel="W"]
    "n1,0" -> "n1,-1" [xlabel="S"]
    "n1,-1" -> "n1,0" [xlabel="N"]
}
```

Image:
[image: mud map graph made by graphviz neato]
[Source](https://forum.graphviz.org/t/how-to-draw-horizontal-and-vertical-edges-between-to-node/1299/2)

---

Or a more complex solution with `dot` engine:

```
digraph Mud_Map {
    layout=dot
    splines=ortho
    nodesep=.5
    
    // our custom grid
    node [shape=box]
    // arbitrary path on rigid grid
    A0 -> B0 [xlabel="E"]
    B0 -> A0 [xlabel="W"]
    B0 -> B1 
    B1 -> B0

    // main "underground" grid:
    edge [style=dashed color=dimgrey]
    // uncomment line below to hide the grid:
    //edge [style=invis]
    // uncomment line below to hide the A1 node:
    //A1 [shape=none label=""]
    A0 -> A1
    B0 -> B1
    rank=same {A0 -> B0 }
    rank=same {A1 -> B1 }
}
```

Image without uncomment lines:
[image: mud map graph with showed edges made by graphviz dot]
Image with uncomment lines:
[image: mud map graph with hidden edges made by graphviz dot]
[Reference](https://graphviz.org/Gallery/undirected/grid.html)